# DefaultValue in a Form

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this kind of problem: How to set a defaultValue in the form.

Because when I compile this form, if I leave a white field this is removed from the database.

I read that I should use "defaultValue" but I don't understand how to set it to do this.

```
export default class Modify extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
};
}

 findUser(cf){
  //... call the DB .... 
 //...................
    utente.Person.FirstName = this.state.FirstName;
    utente.Person.LastName = this.state.LastName;


    return global.utente.db.localdb().put(utente);
  })
  // catch and finally 
}

render() {
return (
  <View style={style.container}>
    <View style={style.page}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        <View style={style.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={style.inputs}
            placeholder="Name"
            placeholderTextColor="#56cbbe"
            keyboardType="default"
            underlineColorAndroid="grey"
            onChangeText={FirstName => this.setState({ FirstName })}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={style.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={style.inputs}
            placeholder="Surname"
            placeholderTextColor="#56cbbe"
            keyboardType="default"
            underlineColorAndroid="grey"
            onChangeText={LastName => this.setState({ LastName })}
          />
        </View>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to use a default value in an input field?

Comment: If it is the only way to resolve my problem yes :(

Comment: I added an answer. Hope that solvers the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Default"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="Value"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

You just need to add the tag `Value` to your code so that the input field will already have a value that will be submitted if nothing is typed in.

```
<View style={style.inputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={style.inputs}
            placeholder="Surname"
            placeholderTextColor="#56cbbe"
            keyboardType="default"
            underlineColorAndroid="grey"
            value="DEFAULT VALUE"
            onChangeText={LastName => this.setState({ LastName })}
          />
        </View>
```

I added `value="DEFAULT VALUE"` to your code

Comment: Check more about that here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_value

Comment: Thank for your reply! I don't understand what values to use

Comment: If you look at the coded I added  value="DEFAULT VALUE" 
That will add a default value, Of course you can change the value in the braces

Comment: @Jack23 Also I edited the answer to make it more clear

Comment: ok, I should pass the value and not a string. it is the same?

Comment: You don't need pass another value. You have to add the attribute VALUE to your code. It will be automaticcally be passed as a string

Comment: mmmh the problem is that I have some values in the DB. If I leave the field white  these values ​​are deleted. If i use value="" I don't pass a string as default value in the db? ( for example I should pass the last firstname that the user chooses)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195980/discussion-between-synapsis-and-jack23).